# Visual Studio 2013: Building problems

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Every time I build project, I get error "Access denied to PDB". Every time I switch configuration to release, build, then switch configuration again to debug and build. Can you please to advise anything to return to normal work

Comment: Have you tried performing a clean before rebuilding?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens to me. You can solve this problem by manually navigating to the project's output folder, and remove the content (usually `.dll` and `.pdb` files) from the bin folder. then `clean` the solution, and `rebuild`. & Here you go !

Comment: It don't help. I need to do it every time

Comment: @hinduCoder are you connected to TFS?

Comment: No, I'm not connected